# Make header text vertical align bottom

Tags: angular-ui-grid

After rid of nowrap from header text I want to make it bottom
I was trying put vertical-align: bottom everywhere but without success.
Here is example where first column is aligned to top.

```
.ui-grid-cell-contents {
 ....

  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JzJVRgjz2VLELcqcdR4I?p=preview

How to make header text in angular-ui-grid to be bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the height you have in your ui-grid-cell-contents

Try the following...

```
.ui-grid-header-cell-label
{
  line-height:48px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: almost. effect is that half of header text is hidden under first row

Comment: u have a sample of this? I just tried and it looks ok here http://plnkr.co/edit/mXjtp0YfSxtpnDmiWso7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but in v4.0.6 this will wrap the header text and bottom align it:

```
/* To make the header cell text wrap */
.ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
     height: 48px;
     white-space: normal;
     -ms-text-overflow: clip;
     -o-text-overflow: clip;
     text-overflow: clip;
     overflow: visible;
}

/* To bottom align the header text */
.ui-grid-cell-contents .ui-grid-header-cell-primary-focus {
    position: relative;
}
.ui-grid-header-cell-label {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at first make parent tag css property display to table. then child tag (header contents tag) make css property display to table-cell, then vertical-align to bottom. like ..

```
div[role="columnheader"] {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
    height: 58px;
    /* white-space: normal !important; */
    /* -ms-text-overflow: clip; */
    /* -o-text-overflow: clip; */
    /* text-overflow: clip; */
    /* overflow: visible; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```